# Gif not getting animated flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRi8i.gif)Flutter Web Gif Image does not animate.

I am having a TabBarView in my flutter web. Inside that I am having a Image in GIF format. Image is getting displayed but no animation is visible.

```
SizedBox(
                height: 500,
                width: Constants.width,
                child: TabBarView(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.asset(
                      'images/tourism.gif',
                      width: Constants.width,
                    ),

                  ],
                ),
              )
```

Comment: did you mention it in pubspec file?

Comment: yes I have mentioned it. But still it does not work. Image is visible but no animation in the image

Comment: `Image(image: new AssetImage("images/tourism.gif"))`can you try this one

Comment: image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage("images/tourism.gif"),
                              fit: BoxFit.fitHeight)

Comment: This is how i did now. But still it does not work

Comment: None of the gif files are working

Comment: maybe the sizedbox encountering it, try without it

Comment: I have tried with Container now. But not working

Comment: Finally I tried that in the main.dart file also. No animation.

Comment: i can play the gif like that: `Image.network('https://media.giphy.com/media/SYFdypyXAHwCXbzTMX/giphy.gif', width: 70, height: 70,),`

Comment: void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Visa By Masters',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: Image.network(
          'https://media.giphy.com/media/SYFdypyXAHwCXbzTMX/giphy.gif',
          width: 70,
          height: 70,
        ));
  }
}

Comment: That is my code. It does not work

Comment: i cant reproduce it, it works on me

Comment: Was it on a Mobile App or Web?

Answer (score 1):

I just checked how an Image.asset is translated and its apparently converted into a canvas. As you can see in the below image.

[image]

So if you are in an demanding situation you could still achieve this with the usual img element which can be included through the flutter_web_ui package as shown below in the code.

```dart
    import 'package:flutter_web/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_web_ui/ui.dart' as ui;
    import 'dart:html';

    class GifRenderer extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // build the HTML Img element.
        ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
          "Gif Renderer",
          (int viewId) {
            ImageElement element = ImageElement()
              ..src = "/assets/images/tourism.gif"
    //          ..height = 500
    //          ..width = 800
              ..style.border = "none";
            return element;
          },
        );

        return Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 1.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                // This is a normal image asset
                child: Image.asset(
                  '/images/tourism.gif',
                  height: 500,
                  width: 800,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                // Here we add the HTML img element created early.
                child: HtmlView(
                  viewType: "Gif Renderer",
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

So now this code displays two widget in a column first one is usual image asset as you used and the second one is html img element which renders the gif properly.

Also note Flutter-web expects an AssetManifest.json inside your asset folder with the entries relevant to your assets. I am not exactly sure if this mandatory but here is a reference how to define it [AssetManifest.json](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33402).

I used the following entries in my AssetManifest.json

```json
{
   "assets": ["images/tourism.gif"]
}
```